# sending big data over socket by using json

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

the problem is when i send a code with my code i receive the the text wrong like if i send hello i get `b'"hello"'` i want to receive it with out any of these `b'""'`

heres what i have tried:

```
import socket ,json


listner=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

listner.bind(("10.0.2.15", 4444))


listner.listen(0)
print("watin for incomin connictions")

connection, address = listner.accept()

print("connected with "+str(address))


while True:
   command=raw_input(">> ")
   if command=="":
      continue
connection.send(json.dumps(command))
result=b''
   while True:
       try:
           result=result+connection.recv(1024)
       except ValueError:
           continue

print(json.loads(result))

connection.close()`
```

if there's a better way to use to send big data without using json that would be a better solution for me

Comment: Well, if you are writing a server and you do not need own protocol (you can use HTTP for example) you can use Flask that will handle encoding and decoding for you.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i just find a way not sure if its the best way to do this but is works for me i just add a certain string at the end of the massage on send method like `"thetextendhere"` and make a while loop in the receiver method when ever find this word break